# MongoDB database relationships

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have just started to build a database in MongoDB.  I have 2 tables, Teams and Fixtures, and each Fixture document should have 2 links to the Fixtures table, a HomeTeamId and an AwayTeamId.  Is this the correct way to do this?

Teams :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3"
    },
    "TeamName": "Arsenal",
    "BadgeSmall": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Small/arsenal.png",
    "BadgeLarge": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Large/arsenal.png",
    "TeamImage": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Teams/arsenal.png",
    "Formation": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Formations/arsenal.png"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542979c3e4b0e67da1edc807"
    },
    "TeamName": "Aston Villa",
    "BadgeSmall": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Small/astonvilla.png",
    "BadgeLarge": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Large/astonvilla.png",
    "TeamImage": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Teams/astonvilla.png",
    "Formation": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Formations/astonvilla.png"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542c45eee4b0413a3dd4d43e"
    },
    "TeamName": "Crystal Palace",
    "BadgeSmall": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Small/crystalpalace.png",
    "BadgeLarge": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Large/crystalpalace.png",
    "TeamImage": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Teams/crystalpalace.png",
    "Formation": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Formations/crystalpalace.png"
}
```

Fixtures :

Home Team : Aston Villa, Away Team : Arsenal :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542f0dfbe4b0413a3dd4ead4"
    },
    "Date": "2014-09-20",
    "HomeTeamId": "542979c3e4b0e67da1edc807",
    "AwayTeamId": "542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3",
    "HomeTeamScore": 0,
    "AwayTeamScore": 3,
    "HomeTeamScorers": "",
    "AwayTeamScorers": "Ozil 33,Welbeck 34,Cissokho 35 (OG)"
}
```

Home Team : Arsenal, Away Team : Crystal Palace :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542f0f54e4b0413a3dd4ead8"
    },
    "Date": "2014-08-16",
    "HomeTeamId": "542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3",
    "AwayTeamId": "542c45eee4b0413a3dd4d43e",
    "HomeTeamScore": 2,
    "AwayTeamScore": 1,
    "HomeTeamScorers": "Koscielny 45,Ramsey 90",
    "AwayTeamScorers": "Hangeland 35"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would suggest embedding the team objects within the game The team and their icons are unlikely to change within a season.    Makes 1 call instead of 3.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "542f0dfbe4b0413a3dd4ead4"
    },
    "Date": "2014-09-20",
    "HomeTeamId": "542979c3e4b0e67da1edc807",
    "AwayTeamId": "542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3",
    "HomeTeamScore": 0,
    "AwayTeamScore": 3,
    "HomeTeamScorers": "",
    "AwayTeamScorers": "Ozil 33,Welbeck 34,Cissokho 35 (OG)",
    "HomeTeam" : {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "542979c3e4b0e67da1edc807"
        },
        "TeamName": "Aston Villa",
        "BadgeSmall": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Small/astonvilla.png",
        "BadgeLarge": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Large/astonvilla.png",
        "TeamImage": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Teams/astonvilla.png",
        "Formation": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Formations/astonvilla.png"
    },
    "AwayTeam" : {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "542978c4e4b0e67da1edc7f3"
            },
            "TeamName": "Arsenal",
            "BadgeSmall": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Small/arsenal.png",
            "BadgeLarge": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Badges/Large/arsenal.png",
            "TeamImage": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Teams/arsenal.png",
            "Formation": "http://footballcomps.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Formations/arsenal.png"
    }
}
```